# Why does 'Run' query option disappear when I open a saved query in Azure Data Studio?

Tags: azure, azure-data-studio

apologies if I butcher all the terminology because I am very new to SQL and Azure Data Studio. I'm running Azure Data Studio on a MacBook using Docker.

When I create a new query, I get a toolbar of options including 'Run' query. [image]

The toolbar is gone when I save, close, and re-open the query. I can't even run the query using F5.[image]

I'd like to understand how to get the toolbar back on existing queries and why this is happening in general.

I've been creating new queries with copied code and saving over my existing ones as a workaround every time I need to work on a query.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!

When saving the file, change the **format** from 'All Files' to 'SQL'. The toolbar will appear next time you open the file. [image]